# how to resolve firebase ios setup error in react native

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, react-native, apple-m1

I am developing react native app on apple macbook air m1 and getting error while setting up firebase for ios in xcode. I followed official documentation [here](https://rnfirebase.io/) then saw alot of tutorials and questions and done the exact same step but nothing working, I saw somewhere that this has to do something with my firebase version so I tried to update but still no success, I am facing following error in AppDelegate.m
[image]

Comment: Did you import Firebase into AppDelegate? #import <Firebase.h>

Comment: @MikhailVasilev yes I did